# Find in text with Linq

Tags: c#, linq

So I have such construction for searching words in text

```
 FileStream fs = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Open);
 StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(fs);
 fullText = sr.ReadToEnd();
 string[] arr = fullTetx.Split(' ');
 for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++)//
 {
       if (arr[i].Trim() == "LOAD")
           Console.WriteLine(arr[i].Trim());
 }
 sr.Close();
 fs.Close();
```

I must get all similar words ignore case with Linq.

For example:

> LOAD(PLOT) =
>      SET 4 = THRU 16,34 THRU 37,
>          48 THRU 53,61
>      FORCE(PLOT,CORNER)ds
>      STRESS(PLOT,CORNER) mama dad
>      SPC = 1
>      LOAD = 1
>      Load , load.

and I must get:

> LOAD LOAD Load load

Comment: For information : there is a System.IO.File.ReadAllText static method that does what your first 3 lines do : http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.io.file.readalltext%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

Comment: IMO, this question is more suitable for http://codereview.stackexchange.com . Anyway, [here's](http://pastebin.com/ftgJCwGD) simplified version of your code.

Answer (score 4):

I am not sure I understood where LOAD is taken from. Is it hardecoded ? if yes then something like :

```
foreach(var word in arr.Where(w => w.ToUpper() == "LOAD"))
    Console.WriteLine(word);
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this one

```
    var result = arr.Where(x => string.Equals(x, "LOAD",StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)).ToList();
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var matches = Regex.Matches(fullTetx, @"load", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

Answer (score 0):

Or how about:

```
// If you want the lines that contain "LOAD"
var loads = File.ReadLines(fileName).
            SelectMany (l => l.Split(' ')).
            Where (s => s.ToUpperInvariant().Contains("LOAD"));

foreach(var s in loads)
{
    Console.WriteLine(s);
}

// If you just want instances of "LOAD"
var loads = File.ReadLines(fileName).
            SelectMany (l => l.Split(' ')).
            Where (s => s.ToUpperInvariant() == "LOAD");

foreach(var s in loads)
{
    Console.WriteLine(s);
}
```